# Cannot use TransitionGroup in render function while building my custom Tabs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

As I've wrote in the title, I'm trying to build my own Tabs components. So far it's very basic:

`Tabs.vue`

```js
setup(props, { slots }) {
  const { activeTab } = toRefs(props);
  provide("activeTab", activeTab);

  const newSlots = slots.default().map((slot, index) => {
    return h(slot, {
      index, // for each tab to know, whether is active
      key: index, // for TransitionGroup
    });
  });

  return () =>
    h(
      TransitionGroup,
      {
        name: "tabs-fade",
      },
      () => newSlots
    );
}
```

`Tab.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="activeTab === index">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
setup() {
  const activeTab = inject("activeTab");

  return {
    activeTab,
  };
},
```

And I've planned to use it like that:
`Testing.vue`

```html
<ul>
  <li @click="activeTab = 0">1</li>
  <li @click="activeTab = 1">2</li>
  <li @click="activeTab = 2">3</li>
</ul>
<Tabs :activeTab="activeTab">
  <Tab> 1 </Tab>
  <Tab> 2 </Tab>
  <Tab> 3 </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Without **TransitionGroup** everything works fine, although when I'm trying to add it for smoother transitioning, I'm getting an error when trying to switch between the tabs:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <TransitionGroup name="tabs-fade" > 
  at <Tabs activeTab=1 > 
  at <Testing> 
  at <App>

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <TransitionGroup name="tabs-fade" > 
  at <Tabs activeTab=1 > 
  at <Testing> 
  at <App>
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: child.el.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
```

[image: Screenshot of errors]

Comment: PS: If anyone would suggest completly different approach for building this component I'm open to follow your advice ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TransitionGroup` expects a consistent number of children so that it can transition from one state to another. Currently, `Tabs.vue`'s root element is conditionally rendered, such that it's possible for there to be no element at all when the condition is not met, leading to the crash:

```html
<!-- Tab.vue -->
<template>
  <div v-if="activeTab === index"> ❌ when false, no element exists
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### Solution

Add a `v-else` on a `div` to ensure an element always exists in `Tab.vue`:

```html
<!-- Tab.vue -->
<template>
  <div v-if="activeTab === index">
    <slot/>
  </div>
  <div v-else /> 
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-transition-group?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTabs.vue)

Comment: Thank You! Haven't thought of that scenario... Worked like a charm ✨